# lodash or underscore for angular

Tags: angularjs, underscore.js, lodash

I am comparing lodash.js and underscore.js libraries to use with my angular project.

Some research says lodash is more robust and proven one though size wise it is bigger.
My question is which one of these two has better compatibility with Angular 1.X version ?

Can someone answer with at least one reason.

Comment: This is a primarily opinion based question, but you should first determine why you need them. Angular offers many things lodash and underscore have.

Comment: Yeah this is not a question that can be objectively answered. It's a matter of preference. Either one can be used with angular.

Comment: never found underscore lacking enough to warrant using lodash. and even with lodash holding more functionality, you can compliment underscore with underscore-contrib and underscore-string